# Getting css with jquery and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to get some css with jquery in internet explorer.

The css is set in a external file and looks like this:

```
#something a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* since I dont want underline when not hover */
}

#something a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And I want to get if underline is set or not.

This works in firefox and webkit but not IE:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    console.log($(this).css('textDecoration'));
    /* this return underline in FF and Webkit but not in IE */
});
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work in IE?

Comment: @Patrik Hi friend, your code return the correct property i checked in IE7+. which version of IE you are using?Here one think to note that <a> tag by default possess `underline`. so if you dont give any `text-decoration` to it using css, moreover the code will return `underline`

Comment: @abdullah.abcoder Hm... are you sure you tried with :hover? try set #something a { text-decoration: none; } and #something a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } || I will update my example code a bit.

Comment: You question is illogical. Inside the hover event the link will always be underlined, so it's no point in testing if it is. Is your example correct? Do you actually need to know if the link is underlined, or if it's only being hovered?

Comment: @RoToRa I want to know if the element i'm hovering is supposed to have an underline or not.

Comment: @Patrik: But your style sheet says that it will be underlined, so it is.

Comment: console.log wont work in IE that is why. why not simply alert the value if you want to see it?

Comment: @RoToRa yeah, but the javascript doesn't know that. I don't know which links will have underline. I want the code to work on all sites. I don't want to make the code for a specific site.

Comment: @The_Butcher If you enable javascript debug, it works. at least in ie7/ie8. But that was just to show that I want to get the css properties and not set it. It's not the real script I'm working on.

Comment: Ah, ok, so some links are underlined and some not. Why do you need to know if a link is underlined on hover? What are you doing with that information?

Comment: I'm writing a script that underlines the text (haha that sounds quite stupid). No but, Firefox, Webkit and IE all render the underline differently. Webkits and IE<7 underline is only 1px thick no matter what the font-size is. So I want to replace the underline with a border-bottom so it looks the same in all browsers. - Sry, I've been quite bad at explaining.

Comment: Ok, the goal of my questions was to see if there were any alternatives to detecting the underline, but now I know your goal,  see there doesn't seem to be. Let me think about it for a bit...

Comment: What IE is this? A quick test in IE8 worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKqC/

Comment: IE7. The text-decoration: underline in IE8 looks alright so it's not important. Yeah that works but if I want underline while hover it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKqC/1/

Comment: Hm... just saw that on mouse over it returns none and on mouse out it returns underline. Problem is that I need to know it while the user is hovering.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my exmplae was wrong. Anyway based on your example, adding a `setTimeout` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKqC/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `setTimeout` makes it work:

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    var x = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(x.css("text-decoration"));
    }, 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKqC/2/

Comment: Thanks it's working but the hover function is failing. Mouse over works but mouse out doesnt work (same code works in ff/webkit) http://jsfiddle.net/SeaNC/

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
});
```

Comment: Why the negative vote? +1 for the same reason the -1 was originally placed.

Comment: -1 was for not being even close. The OP doesn't want to set underline, he want's to know *if* it's set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Bro:

```
$('a').css('textDecoration', 'none'); //initially set no underline 
$('a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('textDecoration', 'underline'); //set underline in hover in
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('textDecoration', 'none'); // set no underline in hover out
});
```

Comment: @Patrik this code independent form `css` property i.e. if `underline` is set or not to `a`

Comment: -1 for not being even close. The OP doesn't want to set underline, he want's to know *if* it's set.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know if the link should have underline. If i write a:hover { text-decoration: underline } I want the js to check the css and say "this link should have underline" and if I write text-decoration: none; it should say "This link should not be underlined".

Comment: @RoToRa it was my lack to understand OP's view.In future try to avoid this error.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$('a').hover(function() {
     console.log($(this).css('text-decoration'));         
});
```